# Affects of webpart removal

Tags: 2010, web-part

Will removing any web part from SharePoint site at web app level will affect functionality of others. Since Microsoft provides bundle of features, that includes multiple functionalities, so in case removal of any web part will affect others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webparts are deployed as part of SharePoint solution files (wsp). As well as there are standard webparts that are available as part of SharePoint install (content editor etc.)

Removing a webpart from a page will not affect the same webpart installed on other pages. While if you remove a webpart solution it basically remove the webpart files from the farm and that will affect all pages this webpart is referenced.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is I want to hide some of the web parts from the complete web application(that will hide it from each and every page of all site collections of that web application). So in this case will it affect functionalities of other web parts since most of them are part of the same bundle.

Comment: No. Out of the box Webparts are independent. So it will not affect unless you are not removing any of the files (dll, ascx etc.) from the farm